# Android java source explanation

Tags: java, android

```
txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
```

In general
Can anyone tell me what the above line is saying.
Left the objects txtFar & result.

Any idea?

Thanks for your precious time!

Comment: What do you mean by general? Syntactically? Or grammatically (what does `toString()/setText()` do)? If you want us to tell, what this lines does in the context of your application, we need more code for that. I.e. the declarations of txtFar and result would be nice. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is getting the **0th property of result** and setting it  to **txtFar** by converting the property into **String**.

Are you expecting something else?

Answer (score 1):

The OP of this line may be interpreted as:

```
txtFar variable which is a text field is set to 0th property of result by converting into String.
```

Basically, this text field is assigned a String value.

Comment: How do you know, that txtFar is a text field?